# How to run Node.js app with ES6 features enabled?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I use the [require hook](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/require/) of [BabelJS](https://babeljs.io/) (formerly named 6to5) to run node apps with [es6features](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#readme):

```
// run.js
require("babel/register");
require("./app.js6");
```

I call `node run.js` to run my **app.js6**. I need to install BabelJS and provide a **run.js** for each project I'd like to use es6features. I would prefer a call like `nodejs6 app.js6`. How can I achieve this system independently (Unix and Windows)?

Comment: Have you considered using io.js instead of NodeJS+Babel? https://iojs.org/en/index.html

Comment: I didn't know io.js. Looks great, but unlike BabelJS it doesn't support [rest arguments](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#default--rest--spread).

Comment: Right. Well keep an eye on it, it's moving fast unlike NodeJS so I'm sure it'll be supported soon.

Comment: Are you looking for `babel-node`? https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/#babel-node

Comment: Might want to check out https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-register-cli

Comment: Simple solution successfull with node 13.5, express 6.13.4 https://timonweb.com/tutorials/how-to-enable-ecmascript-6-imports-in-nodejs/

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Add the `babel-cli` and `babel-preset-es2015` (aka ES6) dependencies to your app's package.json file and define a `start` script:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "babel-node --presets es2015 app.js"
  }
}
```

Then you can simply execute the following command to run your app:

```
npm start
```

If you ever decide to stop using Babel (e.g. once Node.js supports all ES6 features), you can just remove it from package.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  }
}
```

One benefit of this is that the command to run your app remains the same, which helps if you are working with other developers.

Comment: It should be noted that the babel docs explicitly [warn against using babel-node in production](http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/#babel-node).

Comment: What about `nodemon` or others with your settings? Are you really reload server manually every time you make changes to files while developing?

Comment: From the docs:
You should not be using babel-node in production. It is unnecessarily heavy, with high memory usage due to the cache being stored in memory. You will also always experience a startup performance penalty as the entire app needs to be compiled on the fly.

Comment: Update: es of 2017, the preferable common preset is [preset-env](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-env/). And as long, as that is installed, it doesn't even need to be specified...

Comment: ...thus, as long as `babel-cli` and `preset-env` is installed, and if you like things directly (w/o npm run... and the package.json-editing required) the command (issued from project root) is: `$> ./node_modules/.bin/babel-node yourToolhere.js`

Comment: Why would i need all those dependencies just to run a certain js version

Answer (score 39):

How configure **node.js app with es6 support and server reload on file change**.

---

### I.Configuration steps ( creating project from the scratch ):

1.Go in terminal to Your project main directory

`npm init` //create package.json for project

2.Install dependencies

```
npm install --save-dev babel
npm install --save-dev babel-cli
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-0 //*1
npm install --save-dev nodemon
```

*1 - it can be also stage-1 or 2, it depends what features of es We want to use*

3.We should have in package.json file something like that ( for sure package version will be different but it is ok ):

```
"devDependencies": {
  "babel": "^6.5.2",
  "babel-cli": "^6.16.0",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
  "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.16.0",
  "nodemon": "^1.11.0"
}
```

4.Create .babelrc file in root project directory ( there is package.json file )

```
{
 "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0"]
}
```

5.Create two directories:

**src** - here is working directory with files writen in es6

**dist** - here files will compile to es5 using babel

Your project root directory should look like this:

- project

  - src

    - index.js //main project file
  - dist
  - package.json
  - .babelrc

7.Add to **package.json** needed commands:

```
"scripts": {
  "watch": "babel -w src/ -d dist/",
  "build": "babel src/ -d dist/",
  "serve": "babel -w src/ -d dist/ | nodemon --watch dist",
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
}
```

8.Available commands:

`npm run watch` //starts watch watch changes in src directory and compiles in to dist

`npm run build` //compiles files from src directory to dist

`npm run serve` //it is doing watch + start node server, on every file change it will restart node server using nodemon which is watching dist directory changes

9.Final notes

- Server will run dist/index.js file as main file.
- File dist/index.js will be compiled from src/index.js so there should be main file of project.
- dist directory should be added to ignore by git ( but not ignore it for npm if it will be a node package )

10.Run server and start creating app in **src** directory.

```
npm run serve
```

---

### II. Easier way ( ready to use boilerplate )

If it is too many points for You then full woking boilerplate is available on github - https://github.com/maciejsikora/node-express-babel-boilerplate.

Comment: the problem this transpilation just convert the js files and does not include the node modules inside

Comment: create second build command like - "build-modules": "babel node-modules/ -d dist/",

Comment: According to the babel itself, `babel` package, is a no-op in Babel 6.
Babel's CLI commands have been moved from the `babel` package to the `babel-cli` package.
Consider installing `@babel/core` and `@babel/cli` instead. Change the scripts to `"babel src -d dist"`

Answer (score 17):

You can use node with --harmony flag to run script with es6 features

Comment: Node with --harmony flag doesn't support [rest arguments](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#default--rest--spread). A feature that is supported by BabelJS and that I'd like to use.

Comment: You can see that **rest parameters** are supported now https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#node8_10

Answer (score 7):

1. `node -r babel-register scripts.js`

This is the best solution

2. `npx babel-node scripts.js`

!Babel node doesn't work well in case of exit process and `kexec` package also doesn't help in this case (as I tried)

In both cases you need to use `.babelrc` which should describe presets and plugins for your app.

`npx` is using only for execution of libraries which are not installed with `npm` or `yarn` . Otherwise you need to `npm i -g babel-cli` and then `babel-node script.js`

Comment: node -r babel-register scripts.js works like charm and quite simple in dev

Answer (score 6):

you need to install [`babel-register`](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/require/) and [`babel-preset-es2015`](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2015/) preset Which used into `babel-register` options to Enabled convert `ES6` to `ES5` on-the-fly transpilation

```
 npm install babel-register

 npm install babel-preset-es2015
```

your **run.js** file:

```
// require babel-register and set Babel presets options to es2015
require('babel-register')({
   presets: [ 'es2015' ]
});

require("./app.js6");
```

**Notice**: Now you does not need `.babelrc` file to set [`Babel presets`](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/#options) options As we setting it with `require` method

Comment: It has some warning regarding production use https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation

Not meant for production use
The require hook is primarily recommended for simple cases.

Comment: in this case, how am I going to run my app in production? Do I need to compile my files down to es5? :/

Comment: @sandip_rb yes you must compile your files before going to production.
you must figure out this solution works for `node.js` versions doesn't support `ES6` (less than 4.x versions), Now `node.js` version support  `ES6`

Comment: @sandip_rb see useful link about use babel into production -> https://medium.com/@Cuadraman/how-to-use-babel-for-production-5b95e7323c2f#.qovdqz4bm

Answer (score 3):

> I would prefer a call like `nodejs6 app.js6`.

You may try the wrapper solution with babel-core api:

```
// Save as es6.js

var babel = require("babel-core");
var argc = process.argv.length;

babel.transformFile(process.argv[argc - 1], function (err, result) {
    eval(result.code);
});
```

Run your es6 featured script with `node es6 thefile.js`

**Reference**: offical [usage doc](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/api/)

Answer (score 3):

`npm init es6`

It creates a `package.json` file with the `"type": "module"` setting.

Comment: The [Active LTS](https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/) version of Node (v16 at this time) and beyond have most [ES6 features](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features) enabled by default. Setting `type` to `module` in `package.json` only enables the `import`/`export` syntax. This has the side effect of disabling `require()` and not setting certain globals like `__dirname` which may not always be desirable.

Answer (score 1):

As of babel 6, you now must install `babel-register` and use the following

```
require("babel-register");
```

Be sure to also install the babel es2015 preset.

Answer (score 1):

Refer this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51485027/1549191

or this boilerplate:

[Boilerplate: node-es6](https://github.com/priyanshuchauhan/node-es6)

Answer (score 0):

Since most of the answers on this page don't work anymore, this is the latest way as of May 2023:

#### Step 1: Install the necessary packages

In your project directory, run the following command to install the required packages:

`npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/cli @babel/preset-env`

This will install Babel core, the command line interface, and the preset for compiling modern JavaScript code.

#### Step 2: Configure Babel

Create a file named `babel.config.json` in the root directory of your project and add the following contents to it:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

This tells Babel to use the `@babel/preset-env` preset, which includes support for the latest JavaScript syntax.

#### Step 3: Update your `package.json` file

Open your package.json file and add the following script to the scripts section:

```
   "dev": "babel -w src -d lib | nodemon lib",
```

**This is just an example and it can change based on your project structure.**
This script compiles your JavaScript files from the `/src` directory to the `/lib` directory, and then runs `nodemon` on the compiled files. Note that this script assumes that your main entry file is named `index.js`.
A more general script would be:

```
"<script name>: "babel -w <code directory> -d <final/dist directory> | <other scripts for running the server>"
```