# require('babel/register') doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have isomorphic app written in ES6 on client with [Babel transpiler](http://babeljs.io/). I want my express server to have the same ES6 syntax as client code.

Unfortunately `require('babel/register')` doesn't work..

#### server.js

```
require('babel/register'); // doesn't work
// require('babel-core/register); doesn't work..

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const port = process.env.NODE_PORT || 1995;

const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const address = require('network-address');

let app = express();

app.set('port', port);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
   res.send('Hello!');
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
   console.info('Demo app is listening on "%s:%s" env="%s"', address(), app.get('port'), env);
});
```

Comment: What are you using `babel/register` for here?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`require('babel/register')` doesn't transpile the file it is called from. If you want server.js to be included in on-the-fly transpilation, you should execute it with `babel-node` (Babel's [CLI replacement](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/) for `node`).

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29415291) for an example.

Comment: Use `require('babel-core/register')` with Babel 6

Comment: @FilipSpiridonov It's now `require('babel-register')`.

Comment: note it does say not to use this (babel-node) in production

Comment: it's now `require(@babel/register)`

Comment: It doesn't even work without a whole bunch of parameters and jumping through the hoops, so look for the answer below.

Answer (score 48):

Since `Babel 6` use [`babel-register hook`](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/require/) to make on-the-fly transpilation.

First:

```
 npm install babel-register
```

Then require it with:

```
require('babel-register');    
// not using 
// require('babel/register');
// or 
// require('babel-core/register);
```

**To** Convert your `Ecmascript 6` code to `ecmascript 5`, you must set [`Babel presets`](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/#options) option with require `babel-register` Like this:

```
require('babel-register')({
  presets: [ 'es2015' ]
});
```

Unlike the answer of [@alexander-pustovalov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29207878/requirebabel-register-doesnt-work/34499455#34499455) you do not need to `.babelrc` file.

you must also install [`babel-preset-es2015`](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2015/):

```
npm install babel-preset-es2015
```

Finally your **Server.js** file will be:

```
require('babel-register')({
   presets: [ 'es2015' ]
});

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const port = process.env.NODE_PORT || 1995;

const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const address = require('network-address');

let app = express();

app.set('port', port);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
   res.send('Hello!');
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
   console.info('Demo app is listening on "%s:%s" env="%s"', address(), app.get('port'), env);
});
```

Answer (score 9):

I ran into a similar issue trying to render a react page (.jsx) on the server.
I fixed it by putting the snippet below at the top of my server file

```
require('babel-register')({
    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
});
```

make sure you have npm `babel-preset-es2015` and `babel-preset-react` installed

Comment: THANK YOU for posting! You solved my problem i've had for 2 days now! The documentation for babel is **terrible**!

Comment: I was trying to use the pure `require` without the presets, and it was causing a syntax error originating from the .jsx component that I was trying to get onto the server... adding the `presets` option solved the problem, THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 9):

In the eve of 2019 we still have no good documentation in JS-related libraries, but, on the other hand, we have StackOverflow for that.

In order to use `babel` on Node.js, you need to

1. `npm install @babel/register @babel/core @babel/preset-env`
2. Create a file `pre-index.js` with attached contents
3. Run `node pre-index`

You can use `import`s and other features only in `index.js` and files it `import`s or `require`s.

```
require('@babel/register')({
    presets: [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
                targets: {
                    node: "current"
                }
            }
        ]
    ]
});
require('./index.js');
```

Answer (score 7):

According to this [document](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/require/)  you have to use:

```
require("babel-register");
```

Additionally, you have to put .babelrc file in the root of directory from which you start server.

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

steps to fix this:

1. remove `require('babel/register');` from server.js
2. create another entry file called start.js
3. in start.js,

   `require('babel/register');
    module.exports = require('./server.js');`

The result is that all code inside server.js will be transpiled on the fly by the register. Please make sure you have configured babel correctly with a .babelrc having the content like below

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0"]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Since Babel 7 use, you can use [@babel/register](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-register)

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/register
```

or

```
yarn add --dev @babel/core @babel/register
```

if you're using [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/).

In the code you just include the following line:

```
require("@babel/register");
```

Comment: @SebastianSchürmann could you elaborate on your downvote, I don't quite get what you mean by checking out the dependency to a local folder. He simply wanted to transpile the file the `require("@babel/register")` is called from, right?

Answer (score -4):

You need to compile your code *using* Babel.
Check out the [docs](http://babeljs.io/docs/using-babel/) from their website.

Install `babel` with `npm install -g babel` then do `babel app.js > compiledApp.js` to compile your ES6 code into ES5 code. You can then run `compiledApp.js`.

The runtime `babel/register` is still needed if your want to use some functions of ES6 like `Object.assign` which are not compiled but executed thanks to a polyfill. 
(Check [here](http://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es6/#math-number-string-object-apis) for examples and more details)

**Edit:** As said in the comment, you can use the `register` to compile on the fly. But it will compile modules you are requiring after this `register`. It will hook the `require` function from `node`. More [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/require/). 
You will still need to compile the file where the `register` or to not use any ES6 in this file.

Comment: Actually, `babel/register` will compile modules on the fly (but of course not the module it is located in).