# Errors when running Babel application

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

My current test of Babel is simple.

```
require("babel-core/register");
import Twitter from "twitter";
```

I get the error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`, which indicates that I have not gotten Babel to work correctly.

When running `node index.js` it does not work. It does work when running `babel-node index.js`

I thought the require hook was supposed to allow ES6 to work at any time. If it only works when using babel-node, can someone explain why? Thank you!

My .babelrc file is

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015"
  ]
}
```

My dependencies in my package.json are

```
"dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.3.17",
    "babel-core": "^6.3.26",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-register": "^6.3.13",
    "twitter": "^1.2.5"
  }
```

Comment: Duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29207878/requirebabel-register-doesnt-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`babel-register` will not change the current file, but all subsequent required files. It means you can do something like this:

```
require('babel-core/register');
require('./app.js');
```

And use ES6 in `app.js` and in everything that's required from there.

Answer (score 1):

For specific documentation on the Babel require hook, please see [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/require/)

Install:

```
$ npm install babel-register
```

Usage:

```
require("babel-register");
```

Note that **require('babel/register')** doesn't transpile the file it is called from. If you want app.js to be included in on-the-fly transpilation, you should execute it with **babel-node** (Babel's [CLI replacement](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/) for node).