# React/Express - 'Unexpected token <' in call to renderToString()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, react-router

I'm working on setting up server-side rendering for my React/Express app, but I'm encountering a syntax error relating to the call to the `react-dom/server` `renderToString()` method.  I'm loosely following this tutorial - http://crypt.codemancers.com/posts/2016-09-16-react-server-side-rendering/

`index.js` (Express app root):

```
'use strict'
require('babel-register')({
    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
});

const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const app = express()
const React = require('react')
const reactDomServer = require('react-dom/server')
const routes = require('./src/routes.jsx')
const reactRouter = require('react-router')
let { match, RouterContext } = reactRouter

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    match({ routes: routes, location: req.url }, (err, redirect, props) => {
        const appHtml = reactDomServer.renderToString(<RouterContext {...props}/>)
        res.send(renderPage(appHtml))
    })
})
```

However, this causes the error:

```
const appHtml = reactDomServer.renderToString(<RouterContext {...props}/>)
                                              ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

All of the similar examples that I've seen have a straight JSX component dropped in... what am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`babel-register` doesn't process the file it is called from, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29425761/1795821

You'll need to put the `app.get()` called into another file, or use a different method of loading Babel.

So make a new `renderReact.js` file with

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    match({ routes: routes, location: req.url }, (err, redirect, props) => {
        const appHtml = reactDomServer.renderToString(<RouterContext {...props}/>)
        res.send(renderPage(appHtml))
    })
  })
}
```

Then back in your `index.js` do this instead

```
let renderReact = require('./renderReact.js');
renderReact(app);
```

Answer (score 5):

I believe the issue stems from the fact that requiring `babel-register` will not work for the file you import it in, but for files that get imported afterwards. So the JSX syntax of `<RouterContext` will not be picked up by the `renderToString` method. This has happened to me before and including `babel-register` for the syntax never felt clean to me anyway.

What I personally have done and many others do is this: `readDomServer.renderToString(React.createElement(RoutingContext, props))` using the `createElement` method in React, you can accomplish the same thing. This will solve your issue.

Comment: That's great, thank you! I've accepted the other answer because it specifically addresses the correct behavior of `babel-register`, but this is a good answer, too, and I will probably use this one in my actual app.

Comment: No problem @skwidbreth glad you found the solution regardless.

Comment: Is there a way to implement this method for <StaticRouter> element with its args and <App /> being inside it?