# Export es6 class in Babel - Cannot find module

Tags: javascript, gulp, ecmascript-6, babeljs

#### I have seen these two answers on SO:

[Exporting a class with ES6 (Babel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29353728/exporting-a-class-with-es6-babel)

[Trying to export a class as a module ES6 babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29337966/trying-to-export-a-class-as-a-module-es6-babel)

I am not using Browserify, just Gulp and Node, just wanted to preface.

---

#### File/Folder Structure:

./

./gulpfile.js

./_GULP

./_GULP/main_config.es6

./_GULP/_classes/Gcfg.es6

---

#### Question Setup

I am exporting a class `Gcfg.es6` file, like so:

```
export default class Gcfg {
   constructor() {
        this.rootDir = './';
        this.latestDir = './_LATEST/';
        this.srcFolder = './_SRC/';
        ...
   }

    getSrcDir(dir="") {
        return this.srcFolder + dir;
    }
    ...
}
```

In `main_config.es6` I am trying to import:

```
import Gcfg from '_classes/Gcfg';
```

*Following this GitHub post:*

https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/849

I assumed I was doing it all correctly. I am using WebStorm and have a "File Watcher" setup to run Babel on save of a .es6 file. I am not doing anything fancy there, the only optional flags I am using are:

`--source-maps` and `--out-file $FileNameWithoutExtension$.js $FilePath$`

$FileNameWithoutExtension$.js is a WebStorm application variables and just is the file being loaded by the watcher and $FilePath$ is the absolute path to the file.

So the command looks like this (I believe I actually do not see it executed):

`babel --source-maps --out-file main_config.js ./_GULP/` etc for the other files...

All files are processed fine by babel I believe. I see the exports and requires in the generated JS.

### **tl;dr**

In `gulpfile.js` I am doing:

`gCfg = require('./_GULP/main_config');` <- this require works!

However, when I try to run GULP it immediately fails and in the console I get:

```
Error: Cannot find module '_classes/Gcfg'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:286:25)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/_GULP/main_config.js:9:20)
at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
```

#### The Question

Why am I unable to export the class in `Gcfg.es6` and import it into `main.es6` using es6 import/export? Is there a polyfill needed (I am loading bable/polyfill)? Is it that I have `_`'s in my path? I have just been thrashing on this for too long.

Thanks!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Well for one thing you have:

```js
import Gcfg from '_classes/Gcfg';
```

If you're compiling to CommonJS and you don't have anything special setup, Node is going to try to load `node_modules/_classes/Gcfg`. You probably want:

```js
import Gcfg from './_classes/Gcfg';
```

Comment: That was the whole problem? Great!

Comment: @JMM Thanks a lot man, this is exactly what I was doing wrong.