# SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

When I am running index.js its giving error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`. Though I am using babel to convert ES6 to ES5.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "espract",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel src -d lib"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.3.17"
  }
}
```

Person.js

```
'use strict';

module.exports = class Person {
    constructor(firstname, lastname) {
        this.firstName = firstname;
        this.lastName = lastname;
    }

    greet() {
        console.log(`Hello, ${ this.firstName } ${ this.lastName }`);
    }
};
```

index.js

```
import * as Person from './lib/Person';


//es class inherit Person
class Policeman extends Person {

    constructor(firstname, lastname, badgenumber) {
        //call parent constructor
        super(firstname, lastname, badgenumber);
        this.badgeNumber = badgenumber;
    }

    greet(){
        //call parent class method
        super.greet();
        console.log(`License: ${this.badgeNumber}`);
    }

}

var officer = new Policeman("John", "Solan", "1231341314134");
officer.greet();
```

> Note: When I am using `var Person = require('./lib/Person')` its
>   working absolutely fine.

Please guide me I just started learning nodejs.

Comment: Maybe it's the same issue as discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33604470/unexpected-token-import-in-nodejs5-and-babel ?

Comment: Are you transpiling it first? Why would node/browser complain about a `import` token if babel transpiles it to something else?

Comment: @MinusFour I am transpilling it first. But babel file is copied without being transformed.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I have tried that, but still its copying files without tranforming.

Comment: I agree with MinusFour, this looks like your code isn't being transpiled. How are you transpiling? A grunt task? Can you post the transpile code?

Comment: I have written script in package.json running it using `npm run build`

Comment: To be honest, If you are using nodeJS I would strongly suggest migrating to a version that natively supports ES6 - it solves many problems.

Comment: I am using `5.3.0`. Which version i should opt ? :)

Comment: 5.3.0 natively supports ES6 classes :) You only have to change import to require.

Comment: It means i need not to use babel..

Comment: Thanks everybody for your help

Comment: Please read tag descriptions! [tag:babel] is for questions about the Python library with that name! It even explicitly says to use [tag:babeljs] when e JavaScript tool.