# How do I make a library "importable" in ES6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack

I think this is a general question about how to make a library usable with ES6's `import`:

I want to use [DimpleJS](https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple) (a JS library for charts) in my React app.

1. I ran `npm install --save dimple-js`
2. I added `import * from 'dimple-js'` to my React component

At this point I get a `Syntax Error: Unexpected token (2:9)` which is the space after my `import *`.

**Why do I get this error? How should I correctly import this into my project?**

Comment: Webpack, Broswerify ...

Comment: Thanks, this application is using Webpack.  Is there anything in particular about it I should look at?

Comment: See this [link](http://www.2ality.com/2015/04/webpack-es6.html)

Comment: Thanks @peteb - most of the time when I get a package from npm, it works fine. However when I looked at examples (like Lodash) they have "export" in their main files.  This package does not.  Should I be adding 'export' to `/node_modules/dimple-js/dist/dimple.latest.js` manually? I'm assuming not since it will get wiped out on an npm update. So should I be forking this library and making it webpack compatible, or am I missing something?

Comment: Do you have [`babel-loader`](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader) installed?

Comment: I believe so, although it doesn't look like it includes my /node_modules/ folder.  Here is a jsfiddle of my webpack.config.js: https://jsfiddle.net/kt9a0h6u/.  My project structure is simple it's just dist, src, and node_modules folder.

Comment: Yeah, that's fine, because `DimpleJS` doesn't have to be transpiled (it's written in ES5). You have `include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')`, so `babel-loader` is only transpiling files inside that folder. Make sure that your React component is in `src`, or change it to `exclude: 'node_modules'`

Comment: Thanks for the help @PaoloMoretti, really appreciate it!  My React component is inside 'src'

Comment: One more thing: If you use babel 6 you need to add a `.babelrc` file to the root of you project and install the [es2015 preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2015/). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/33608835/63011

Comment: Hmm, but again this isn't a general problem with node_modules, all the others work fine. It's just this one.

Comment: Your syntax is invalid. It must include an `as` clause, as in `import * as dimple from 'dimple-js';`.

Comment: I bet simplle import dimple from 'dimple-js' should work