# Babel ES6 import error, SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

I am trying to set up a basic modular program, however I seem to be running into issues with importing modules. I attempt to import my custom module, I get the following error:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import testStep from 'testStep';
                                                          ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

The code that is causing the issue:

testcase.js

```
import testStep from 'testStep';

testStep.hello();
```

testStep.js

```
var testStep = {
  hello: hello,
};

var hello = () => {
  console.log('hello world');
};

export default {testStep};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "rebuild-poc",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "env"
  ]
}
```

I have already tried several other fixes, such as setting `testStep` as a class, as well as using `require('./testStep.js')`, however neither of those seem to have worked.

Do I have something set up incorrectly with babel or in one of my files?

***Edit: I am running `testCase.js` with `node testCase.js`.

Comment: looks like there is an extra bracket or the extra comma in `testStep`

Comment: `import` can not be inside a function

Comment: @Matthew in es6 trailing comma's are allowed, but i tried it with it removed and it did not fix the issue.

Comment: @JaromandaX could you clarify on that point a bit more? to the best of my knowledge, the import is not inside of a function. It is just in the script, but maybe i am misunderstanding

Comment: it's inside in IIFE (according to the error message) .... `Import declarations are only allowed at the top level of module scope` ... I may be misunderstanding the error output you are getting though now that I've looked more closely at the code in the question

Comment: have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33604470/unexpected-token-import-in-nodejs5-and-babel) look like you have to set the presets to `es2015`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please install `babel-cli` and call your file with: `./node_modules/.bin/babel-node testcase.js`

It will fail. Now we have to fix your code.

testStep.js should look like:

```
var hello = () => {
  console.log('hello world');
};

var testStep = {
  hello: hello,
};

export default testStep;
```

Then, it will work. ;)

This first introduction on https://babeljs.io/ is, that you should install `babel-cli` and `babel-preset-env`. ;)

You can also write your testStep.js like this:

```
var testStep = {
  hello: hello,
};

function hello () {
  console.log('hello world');
};

export default testStep;
```

This keeps the hoisting in mind. Like [Jacob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45293882/1592039) said in his first point.

Answer (score 3):

From the babel 6 Release notes:

**Plugin Presets**

```
$ npm install --save-dev babel-preset-env
```

save it .babelrc file

```
{
  presets: ["env"]
}
```

Note:
https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#docsNav

Comment: Babel recommends to use another package `babel-preset-env`

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to define `hello` with `function`, using `var`, you will not have `function hoisting`, so when declaring `testStep`, `hello` is undefined.
2. If you want to use es module, you can use `babel-register` or `babel-node`.
   In your code,  node can not handle es module.

**Babel-register**

With bebel-register, all your module will be handled by babel when they are imported.

First,`yarn add babel-register babel-cli --dev` or `npm install babel-register
 babel-cli -dev`
Then create an entry file:

```
// entry.js
require('babel-register')
require('testcase')
```

In your testcase, you can use es module now.

Edit you package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "node entry.js"
},
```

you can run `yarn test` or `npm run test` in terminal.

You don't need `babel-polyfill`, that is for browsers, not for node.