# Import Unexpected identifier + SyntaxError: Unexpected string

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, babeljs

I'm having a problem when running jest test. I'm getting an import unexpected identifier

I have already tried by cleaning npm cache and [installing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33604470/unexpected-token-import-in-nodejs5-and-babel) npm babel jest, polyfill, preset-es2015. I've also [read this](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/4604) trying some different configs here and there.

This is my `babel.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/app'
  ],
  env: {
    test: {
      plugins: [
        "transform-strict-mode",
        "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs",
        "transform-es2015-spread",
        "transform-es2015-destructuring",
        "transform-es2015-parameters"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and my `jest config` in package.json

```
"jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "vue"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
      ".*\\.(vue)$": "vue-jest"
    },
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
    }
  }
```

Here is the error.

```
Test suite failed to run

    PCROUTE\Test.test.js:3
    import _interopRequireDefault from "PCROUTE\\node_modules\\@babel\\runtime-corejs2/helpers/esm/interopRequireDefault";
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

I'm expecting to pass the test but I'm getting that error message. I think the problem comes with the env part in the babel.config.js

**Edit: I'm also using windows 7**, and I this can be causing those back and forward mixed slashes.

**Edit2: I just tested it in Linux and it doesn't work.** I have all in forward slashes

```
 PCROUTE/src/tests/Test.test.js:3
    import _interopRequireDefault from "PCROUTE/node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs2/helpers/esm/interopRequireDefault";
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript
```

**Edit 3: I saw a lot of people fixed it with [these lines]**(https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1879#issuecomment-409872897).

```
transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "node_modules/(?!(babel-jest|jest-vue-preprocessor)/)"
  ]
```

in the `jest config file`. I added them and ran this `./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --clearCache` but it doesn't work.

**Edit 4:** I just added a couple of things to my jest file. And deleted a couple in my babel file, and **now I'm getting. `Unexpected String`**

NEW JEST FILE

```
module.exports = {
    moduleFileExtensions: [
      'js',
      'jsx',
      'json',
      'vue'
    ],
    transform: {
      '^.+\\.vue$': 'vue-jest',
      '.+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|svg|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$': 'jest-transform-stub',
      '^.+\\.jsx?$': 'babel-jest'
    },
    transformIgnorePatterns: [
      '/node_modules/'
    ],
    moduleNameMapper: {
      '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1'
    },
    snapshotSerializers: [
      'jest-serializer-vue'
    ],
    testMatch: [
      '**/tests/**/*.test.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)|**/__tests__/*.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'
    ],
    testURL: 'http://localhost/',
    watchPlugins: [
      'jest-watch-typeahead/filename',
      'jest-watch-typeahead/testname'
    ]
  }
```

And I **deleted everything from my babel file** except the `presets: @vue/app` part.

Here is the new error I'm getting.

```
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import "core-js/modules/es6.array.find";
                                                                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected string
```

Comment: what is the command you are using to run the test

Comment: ```npm test``` which runs ```jest```

Comment: have you added babel-jest. Also post jest.config.js

Comment: It's there already, yes, I've added it

Comment: `"PCROUTE\\node_modules\\@babel\\runtime-corejs2/helpers/esm/interopRequireDefault"` I noticed you have mixed backslashes and forward slashes, did you look into that? IF not, the Jest config `transform` and `moduleNameMapper` seem to cause the inconsistency

Comment: Should I use backslashes or forward slashes then?

Comment: I have read a lot about that, and it should be [fixed by now](https://github.com/facebook/jest/commit/aa9790db9bd03a154684574928120e9ee0fb4c8e)

Comment: Not sure about your OS but I would say try both and see if it helps

Comment: I just tested it in linux and I have the same error but with forward slashes only

Comment: Are you sure the env is set to `test`? console `process.env.NODE_ENV` in `babel.config.js` and check once? looks like babel plugins are not being applied. Also try running `NODE_ENV=test npm test` and see if it works.

Comment: @GanapatiVS I just tried with `NODE_ENV=test npm test` and it doesn't work. But what do you mean by env is set to test? And how do I console in babel.config.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After days of struggling with this. I ended up by answering my question. Here I leave all my config files.

### jest.config.js

```
process.env.VUE_CLI_BABEL_TARGET_NODE = true;
process.env.VUE_CLI_BABEL_TRANSPILE_MODULES = true;

module.exports = {
    moduleFileExtensions: [
      'js',
      'jsx',
      'json',
      'vue'
    ],
    transform: {
      '^.+\\.vue$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/vue-jest',
      '.+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|svg|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$': 'jest-transform-stub',
      '^.+\\.jsx?$': 'babel-jest'
    },
    transformIgnorePatterns: [
      '/node_modules/'
    ],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1'
    },
    snapshotSerializers: [
      'jest-serializer-vue'
    ],
    testMatch: [
      '**/tests/**/*.test.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)|**/__tests__/*.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'
    ],
    testURL: 'http://localhost/',
    watchPlugins: [
      'jest-watch-typeahead/filename',
      'jest-watch-typeahead/testname'
    ]
  }
```

### babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/app'
  ]
}
```

### NOTES

- I needed to add [babel core bridge](https://github.com/babel/babel-bridge) to be able to use @babel/core with vue-jest
- It's recommended to clear jest's cache after changing the file

Comment: What do you mean by cache? the yarn.lock file for example ?!

Comment: I have the same issue with another package and I tried a lot of solutions none of them work!

Comment: Which packages?