# basic node.js "function" vs "=>" notation

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have had to modify the code on basic Node.js file in order to make it work and I am wondering why?

this fails:

```
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
```

this works:

```
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
```

Error:

> /my-app/tmp/hello2.js:6 var server = http.createServer((req, res) => { ^ SyntaxError: Unexpected token > at Module._compile (module.js:439:25) at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10) at Module.load (module.js:356:32) at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12) at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10) at startup (node.js:119:16) at node.js:945:3

Complete code

```js
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

//const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
// above *wont work*?? below works
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World\n');
});

// server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
// above *wont work*?? below works
server.listen(port, hostname, function() {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: What error do you get and what version of node are you using?

Comment: /my-app/tmp/hello2.js:6
var server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
                                           ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token >
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:945:3

Comment: Please add the code and error to the QUESTION instead of posting comments. Please see my update of your question

Comment: Although the question is a duplicate, the answers to the other question is outdated. We no longer need Babel for stuff like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your Node.js does not support as standard some functionalities of ES6

Two solutions

1. You have to edit your package.json

   ```
   {
     "dependencies": {
     "babel-cli": "^6.0.0",
     "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.0.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
      "start": "babel-node --presets es2015 app.js"
    }
   }
   ```

   And run `npm start`

   More info on: [How to run Node.js app with ES6 features enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28782656/how-to-run-node-js-app-with-es6-features-enabled)
2. Update your Node.js

   ```
   $ sudo npm cache clean -f
   $ sudo npm install -g n
   $ sudo n stable
   ```

Comment: I think updating to a newer version of Node should be enough, arrow functions are definitely supported in any stable version of Node.

Comment: That is another solution for sure. I'll edit my answer

Comment: had the same problem. i installed new version of node that supported es6. 'nvm use v11.0.0'