# "No Exports Main Defined In" Error Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, nodes, node-modules

I'm trying to make a simple api with js. But i keep getting this stupid error. NOTE: This is my first time programming in js.

Code:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const { Canvas } = require('canvas-constructor')
const canvas = require('canvas')

app.get('/:feed', async (req, res) => {

    const img = await canvas.loadImage('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/30/82/b0/3082b0354572c4d37af6994b4e8baa43.png')

    let image = new Canvas(670, 435)
    .printImage(img, 0, 0, 670, 435)
    .setTextFont('28px Impact')
    .printText(req.params.feed, 40, 150)
    .toBuffer();

    res.set({'Content-Type': 'image/png'})
    res.send(image)//sending the image!

})

app.listen(8080)
```

Error:

```
Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: No "exports" main defined in /home/runner/ScarceExcellentVariables/node_modules/canvas-constructor/package.json
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at throwExportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:440:9)
    at packageExportsResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:692:3)
    at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:482:36)
    at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:522:31)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:919:27)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
```

If anyone could help me i'd appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package you refer to *requires* you to pick what it should use to render graphics. You can import:

- `canvas-constructor/napi-rs` or
- `canvas-constructor/skia-canvas` or
- `canvas-constructor/canvas`

But you can't import `canvas-constructor` by itself. If you pick `napi-rs` you would first need to install that package. A link to these three options are [in the README file](https://github.com/kyranet/canvas-constructor#readme).

---

There are two types of packages:

- **ES6 Modules** (also used in browsers, `import x from "./x.js"`)
- **CommonJS** (older but still supported, `x = require("./x.js")`.

The authors of `canvas-constructor` made sure it works with both.

However, if you use `require()` you may be missing a dependency named  `node:util`. In older Node versions it's only available when using `import`.

Because of this, even though the package is listed as compatible with Node 14 and up, make sure you are using a recent version.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas-constructor

is an ES6 package, while you are using common js (nodejs default) you can either use a different package or modify your nodejs project to use ES6 standards.

To modify your project settings you may wanna follow this answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29415291/13776400